# Android Media.Audio.Playlists always returns no playlists

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, playlist

I want to retrieve all song playlists in an Android device. I have searched online for code samples but the query playlistResolver.query(playlists, null, null, null, null) always gives me size 0. The do loop that prints out the names of the playlists never gets executed. I have tried a few solutions online but all didn't work. Appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
 public void getSongList() {
    //retrieve song info
    ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
    //retrieve playlists
    ContentResolver playlistResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();

    Uri playlists = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor c = playlistResolver.query(playlists, null, null, null, null);
    long playlistId = 0;
    if(c!=null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            String plName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME));
            playlistId = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
            Log.d("PLAYLIST NAME", "PLAYLIST NAME " + plName);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();

    Uri musicUri = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    String isMusic = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!= 0";//only get music tracks
    Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, isMusic, null, null);
    if(musicCursor!=null){
        musicCursor.moveToFirst();
        //get columns
        int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
        int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);
        int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
        int durationColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex
                (MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION);

        //add songs to list
        do {
            long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
            String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
            int thisDuration = musicCursor.getInt(durationColumn);
            //String thisPlaylist = musicCursor.getString(playlistColumn);
            //Log.d("SONG IN PLAYLIST", "SONG " + thisTitle + " IN PLAYLIST " + thisPlaylist);
            songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist, thisDuration));
        }
        while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled against the same issue today. The global storage for playlists would normally be **Phone\Internal storage\Playlists**. The code quoted in the question can retrieve playlists only from that global storage. If a music app creates playlists in its local storage then you can't access those playlists.

I installed two different music apps X and Y.

- Both could create playlists but none of the playlist would go into
  the default storage place
- Each app displayed playlists created by itself. None of the apps
  displayed the playlist created by the other app.

Then I installed a third app Z. It created its playlist in the global storage and I was able to retrieve it using the code in the question. One of the first apps was able to display the playlists crated by Z but it continued to create new playlists in its local storage only.